# How do I view raw memory addreses of MODBUS TCP/IP holding registers in CODESYS

Tags: plc, modbus-tcp, codesys

For a work project, I have to read a bunch of holding registers from an **IFM CR1203 PLC** that is programmed using **CODESYS 3.5**.

The PLC will be running a slave instance and the device reading the holding registers will be a PC running a custom application programmed in Javascript to be a client. I have already programmed MODBUS TCP/IP functions for the custom application that is tested and works (For a previous project I had to do the same for a different PLC programmed using a different platform).

My current issue is that I need the raw memory address of the first holding register to do this, but I can't find it on the CODESYS IDE. CODESYS uses an addressing system that makes it easy for different CODESYS-based devices to communicate. Here is a link that explains how it works: [CODESYS MODBUS register location guide](https://help.codesys.com/api-content/2/codesys/3.5.14.0/en/_cds_operands_addresses/#:%7E:text=When%20defining%20an%20address%2C%20you,and%20the%20memory%20range%20position.)

The only thing that looks like it can work is from the link above:

```
<memory position> : <number> ( .<number> )* // Depends on the target system
```

But I don't fully understand what all that means.

I also can't find any documentation on the PLC or CODESYS that explains this topic in enough detail. Here is a snippet of dummy code used for testing that shows the CODESYS addresses:

[image]

Can someone please explain to me how I can convert the value `%IW0` to a raw memory address, for example, `0xFFFF`?

Answer (score 0):

I use Machine Expert (Codesys 3.5.16) and in their [documentation](https://product-help.schneider-electric.com/Machine%20Expert/V1.1/en/m251prg/m251prg/Ethernet_Configuration/Ethernet_Configuration-11.htm#XREF_D_SE_0002964_6) says:

> The I/Os are mapped to Modbus registers from the master perspective as follows:
>
> - %IWs are mapped from register 0 to n-1 and are R/W (n = Holding register quantity, each %IW register is 2 bytes).
> - %QWs are mapped from register n to n+m -1 and are read only (m = Input registers quantity, each %QW register is 2 bytes).

So in your example they should be address 0 and 1.